# Crystal Reports - If date field is greater than today then today else date field

Tags: date, if-statement, crystal-reports

I am working on a contract and need a date to be the current date `if {month3}` is after the current date.

I have tried it every way imaginable, I have 2 scenarios where `if {month3}` is after the current date it prints `{month3}`, but `if {month3}` is prior to the current date it prints the current date and hides part of the text above it.

It works on one but not the other,  Go easy on me, it's my first post!

```
IF TOTEXT({Month3},"MMMM dd, yyyy") >= TOTEXT((Currentdate),"MMMM dd, yyyy") THEN
    TOTEXT((Currentdate),"MMMM dd, yyyy")  
ELSE
    TOTEXT({Month3},"MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

*{Month 3} = 7/30/2020*
*From contract signing to July 30, 2020
From July 07, 2020  to the start of the official event date*

the other one is right
*{month3} = 5/18/20*
Top sentence is hidden and it says:
*From July 07, 2020 to the start of the official event date*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you compare text-strings instead of dates. Remove the `TOTEXT`-function  and set the date format directly on the properties of the formula field.

```
IF {Month3} >= Currentdate THEN
    Currentdate
ELSE
    {Month3}
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much!